# Robocopy Copy "For Loop"

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I'm trying to create a simple script that will robocopy several folders using the command below. When one folder is done copying, it moves on to the next. Does anyone have a batch/powershell for loop example for this? I've searched around but couldn't find anything.

`robocopy “\\SOURCESERVER\FOLDER\” “\\DESTSERVER\FOLDEr” /S /E /COPY:DATS`

Comment: Copy parent folder instead?

Comment: Your terminology is confusing; are you sure you didn't mean `\\sourceserver\share\folder` ?

Comment: The title is confusing as well, there is no loop.

Comment: I'll see if I can update the title. I was looking for a "for loop" that would process each command in order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't quite understand your question but it seems to me that it's a simple matter of creating a batch file thusly:

robocopy “\SOURCESERVER\FOLDER1\” “\DESTSERVER\FOLDER1” /S /E /COPY:DATS

robocopy “\SOURCESERVER\FOLDER2\” “\DESTSERVER\FOLDER2” /S /E /COPY:DATS

robocopy “\SOURCESERVER\FOLDER3\” “\DESTSERVER\FOLDER3” /S /E /COPY:DATS

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for the response. To clear things up, I just want to create a batch script that will run exactly what you posted above, in order. If I were to put that in a script, would it complete FOLDER1 copy and then move on to FOLDER2 when it's done, or would it kick them all off at the same time?

Comment: A batch file like the one above would process one line at a time in order. So it would process line 1 and then when line 1 completes it will process line 2, etc.

Comment: Glad to help...